# Десериализация xml C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<feed xml:base="http://sds.lhp.ru/DataService.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<id>http://sds.lhp.ru/DataService.svc/UsersTDO</id><title type="text">UsersTDO</title>
<updated>2016-03-21T12:50:17Z</updated><link rel="self" title="UsersTDO" href="UsersTDO" />
<entry>
    <id>http://sds.lhp.ru/DataService.svc/UsersTDO('002530')</id>
    <category term="DataService.UsersTDO" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" title="UsersTDO" href="UsersTDO('002530')" /><title /><updated>2016-03-21T12:50:17Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:ActiveDirectoryID>002530</d:ActiveDirectoryID><d:FullName>Иванов Иван Иванович</d:FullName>
            <d:Surname>Иванов</d:Surname><d:FirstName>Иван</d:FirstName><d:Patronymic>Иванович</d:Patronymic>
            <d:DepartmentName>ОЭО</d:DepartmentName><d:Position>Заведующий группой</d:Position>
            <d:Domain>lhp.ru</d:Domain><d:Login>IvanovII</d:Login><d:Email>sdggsd@dgdg.ru</d:Email>
            <d:LocalPhone>7341</d:LocalPhone><d:WorkPhone>+7(999)99999</d:WorkPhone><d:CellPhone m:null="true" />
            <d:Room>10-03а</d:Room>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

в данной xml нужно добраться до значений FirstName, Surname, Patronymic и DepartmentName, но что-то совсем не выходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить эти значения.

```
XDocument empDoc = XDocument.Load("UsersTDO.xml");

        var users = from entries in empDoc.Descendants("entry")
            select new
            {
                FirstName = entries.Element("FirstName").Value

            };

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.FirstName);

        }
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код, с помощью которого вы пытаетесь десериализовать xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть море разных путей. Например, через `XDocument`.

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var nsm = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
var nsd = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");

var xml = XDocument.Parse(content); // или XDocument.Load(...)

var entries = xml.Descendants(ns + "entry");
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    var props = entry.Descendants(nsm + "properties").Single();
    var surname = props.Element(nsd + "Surname").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(surname);
}
```

---

Вы в общем-то делаете более-менее правильно, но вы забыли указать namespace.

---

Если вам нужно вытянуть всю информацию (то есть, получить адекватную объектную модель), вам стоит, наверное, посмотреть в сторону честной десериализации (объявить дерево классов, расставить необходимые атрибуты и т. д.).

Comment: нет, нет, мне вашего примера с неймспейсами хватило чтобы разобраться. В них и состоял мой камень преткновения.

Comment: @astral: Вот и отлично! Хорошо, что разобрались.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы на вашем месте создал бы классы из данной XML'ки при использовании генераторов классов из Visual Studio. Копируете XML в буфер обмена, а затем в Visual Studio *Edit --> Paste Special --> Paste XML as Classes*.

Но для этого должно быть одно условие - XML должен быть валидным. Для проверки XML на валидность можно воспользоваться различными онлайн-инструментами, как например http://www.xmlvalidation.com/. Для того, что бы сделать вашу XML'ку валидной, надо в её конец добавить тэг:

```
</feed>
```

Ну а затем бы просто десериализировал данный файл:

```
var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
var entry = (entry) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Ну а затем из полученного объекта entry пробрался бы до нужных свойств:

```
var firstName = entry.content.properties.FirstName;
```

Comment: Ничего себе, мегафича. Не знал.

Comment: @VlaD: да. Очень удобно, особенно если надо по быстрому что-то создать. Код генерируется не плохой, но лучше допилить его напильником.

Comment: Ага, как раз экспериментирую. Спасибо!