# Добавление API в C#

Tags: c#

как добавить API в приложение с Windows Forms ?

У меня есть login и password + пример подключения для js:

```
https://api.eway.in.ua/?
login=login&password=pass
&function=general.GetSystemInfo
&format=xml
```

Comment: HttpClient вам в помощь.

Comment: то есть api? Как отправлять запросы?

Comment: @tym32167 Сделал, но как теперь структурировать информацию, полученную в ответ ?

Comment: [Десериализация xml C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506338/179763), [Парсинг сложной Xml в С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/721076/179763),